# コーディング規約を自動化するツールをおしえてください

Tags: プログラミング言語

[コーディング規約を自動化する - プログラマが知るべき97のこと](http://xn--97-273ae6a4irb6e2hsoiozc2g4b8082p.com/%E3%82%A8%E3%83%83%E3%82%BB%E3%82%A4/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E8%A6%8F%E7%B4%84%E3%82%92%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E5%8C%96%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

> コードの整形処理をビルドプロセスに含めてしまう。コードのコンパイルをする度に、誰もが必ず、自動的に整形することになる。

とありますが、自動整形するツールで定番のものはあるのでしょうか。
それとも自分で作っているのでしょうか。

また、こういったツールの総称ってなんでしょう??(これがわからなかったのでググれませんでした)

ちなみに普段触る言語は以下のようになっています。該当するツールなどがあれば教えて下さい。

- JavaScript
- HTML
- Haml
- CoffeeScript
- PHP
- Ruby
- CSS
- SCSS

Comment: 『コーディング チェック ツール』とか『静的 解析 ツール』でぐぐると良い気がします。対象の言語をキーワードに含めてやれば、いくらか出てくるように感じます。
Visual Studioだと『Ctrl + K, D』で自動整形してくれますね。『Style Cop』って規約チェックツールもあります。Eclipse＋Javaだと『Check Style』だったかな？ってのもあります。

Comment: あと、普段触る言語の開発に利用しているIDEやエディタを上げると、同じツールを使ってる人から良いアドバイスが聞ける気がしますね。

Comment: @豚吐露  記事では "ビルドプロセスに含める" となっているので、 IDE でどうこうする話ではなさそうです。 恐らく Jenkins やその他の CI ソフトウェアの利用を前提としているんだと思います。あと `StyleCop` って C# のコードチェッカーでしたっけ。

Comment: なるほど。ちょっと勘違いしていました。ってことは独立した外部ツール的なイメージですね。
StyleCopはC#のコードチェッカーですね。

Answer (score 2):

一般には、コードの整形に属する作業だと思います。
またHTMLの整形ツールとして有名なものに「[HTML Tidy](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy)」がありますが、ここからツール／ライブラリ名に「～tidy」とついているもの、またperlの文化ではbeutifulの代わりにprettyという表現が使われることがあったので「～pretty」とついているものを見かけます。これらも検索語として役立つと思います。
以下などで検索してみることをお勧めします。

- `コード`+`整形`
- `(言語名)`+`tidy`
- `(言語名)`+`pretty`

Answer (score 1):

Eclipseのクリーンアップ機能か保管アクションで可能です。

ほかのIDEにも似た機能がついているのではないでしょうか。

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/jp/opensource/library/os-eclipse-clean/

http://qiita.com/jabaraster/items/96a61e768b3d51909166

Answer (score 1):

PHP や Ruby ではこういったものがあります。

- PHP - [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) や [PHP Coding Standards Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/)
- Ruby - [ruby-beautify](https://github.com/erniebrodeur/ruby-beautify) や [Rubocop](http://batsov.com/rubocop/)

その他の言語も探してみたんですが、オンライン上での自動整形を謳ったものばかりで、CI のように自動実行できるようなものではなさそうでした。
探せばあると思いますが、そのあたりはより知恵のある人にお任せします。

Answer (score 1):

挙げられている言語が、スクリプト言語やマークアップ言語であるため、コンパイル言語で使われているツール相当のものは存在しないように思われます。
（またリンク先の記事は、コンパイル言語を前提としているように読めます）

スクリプト言語の場合は、外部ツールを利用するのではなく、テキストエディタに整形ツールを組み込み、定期的に手動で実行することになります。
（コンパイル（≒ビルド）のタイミングが無いので）